# msChart missing lines

Tags: mschart

I have created a graph based on a datset using VS2010 framework 4.0. I get a report that displays the plotted points but not the connector lines. Is there a reference that needs to be set? I downloaded a msChart sample that imports web.ui.datavisualization.chart but that is not available in my imports that I can see.

Any assistance is appreciated.

[image: chart]

Comment: You graph looks like you are importing your data as separate series instead of one series with multiple points. Provide the code you used to bind your data.

Comment: The chart is in an rdlc file I call chart1.rdlc. This is bound to a dataset that in the above case returns a table that contains 3 rows of data, the year and the number of tests. Since this is my first attempt, I could be way off base as to how this should be accomplished.

Comment: There's clearly 3 series appearing in your legend, so your binding must be incorrect in some way. I don't know much about RDCL i'm afraid. I do all my plotting programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Dominique I was pointed in the direction of the "Drop series field here" grouping on the chart. Once that was removed I was able to see the graphing lines, rather than have the chart think it had (3) distinct groups it was 1 group over several years.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to hear my comment helped.